# what is best HBase client API for java

Tags: java, api, hadoop, hbase

Im working on a project in which i got to use hbase.The project is in java based. I need to know what is the best hbase client api for java.

Comment: I'll assume that you're asking about whether you should write Java code directly or access HBase via REST. The answer depends on the needs of your application.

Comment: i want to ask that how to connect to hbase using java. so there must be an api for it. i want to download that but uptill now im unable to do so

Comment: The HBase site has complete instructions on downloading and installing HBase. Start there: http://hbase.apache.org/book/book.html

Comment: i found it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HBase has its own java client in core library. It covers pretty much everything. (Got connection as well). If you need a asynchronous client You can check [asyncbase](https://github.com/stumbleupon/asynchbase) from stumbleupon, which is a solid client. But it's filter support is limited.(it has basic filters though, and they work like charm). If you are using java I wouldn't recommend using via rest.

Answer (score 6):

Kundera is a recommend client for use.
the author is work hard for it.

Answer (score 2):

Kundera is a object-datastore mapping tool for Hbase alongwith Cassandra and MongoDB.

Some of the salient features are:

- JPA 2.0 compliant.
- Column/ column family indexing using lucene.
- Support for entity relationships and JPA queries.
- Cross-datastore persistence

It's hosted here: 
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera

Comment: Do you store the lucene index of column/column family on hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

playOrm is a another java tool where you can annotate your entities and immediately be up and running.  It is NOT JPA compliant on purpose as nosql is too different.  It has methods like findAll() as you want to parallel your reads in nosql.

playOrm does add JQL but with a twist for nosql....As an example of the twist, you can partition a trillion row into 1 billion partitions and do JQL into any partition and join with other tables.  It makes a transition to noSql much easier if you come from the JPA world.

Answer (score 1):

[HBaseExecutor](https://cdn.rawgit.com/landawn/AbacusUtil/master/docs/HBaseExecutor_view.html), a simple wrapper of HBase Java client. Comparing to the native HBase Java Driver, HBaseExecutor has below features:

- Provides consistent/Integrated/Concise APIs for operations(CRUD) with  entity/String.
- Wrappers for the bytes parameters/operations to improve operability.

Here is a simple sample with HBaseExecutor

```
Account account = createAccount();

// Insert is supported by Model/entity
hbaseExecutor.put("account", toAnyPut(account));

// Get is supported by Model/entity
Account dbAccount = hbaseExecutor.get(Account.class, "account", AnyGet.valueOf(account.getId()));
N.println(dbAccount);

// Delete the inserted account
hbaseExecutor.delete("account", AnyDelete.valueOf(account.getId()));
```

Comparing to the sample with HBase Java client:

```
Account account = createAccount();

// Insert an account into HBase store
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(account.getId()));
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("firstName"), Bytes.toBytes(account.getName().firstName().value()));
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("lastName"), Bytes.toBytes(account.getName().lastName().value()));
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("contact"), Bytes.toBytes("city"), Bytes.toBytes(account.getContact().city().value()));
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("contact"), Bytes.toBytes("state"), Bytes.toBytes(account.getContact().state().value()));
put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("createTime"), Bytes.toBytes(""), Bytes.toBytes(N.stringOf(account.createTime().value())));

hbaseExecutor.put("account", put);

// Get the inserted account from HBase store
Result result = hbaseExecutor.get("account", new Get(Bytes.toBytes(account.getId())));
CellScanner cellScanner = result.cellScanner();
while (cellScanner.advance()) {
    final Cell cell = cellScanner.current();
    N.println(Bytes.toString(cell.getFamilyArray(), cell.getFamilyOffset(), cell.getFamilyLength()));
    N.println(Bytes.toString(cell.getQualifierArray(), cell.getQualifierOffset(), cell.getQualifierLength()));
    N.println(Bytes.toString(cell.getValueArray(), cell.getValueOffset(), cell.getValueLength()));
    // ... a lot of work to do
}

// Delete the inserted account from HBase store.
hbaseExecutor.delete("account", new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(account.getId())));
```

(Declaration：I'm the developer of HBaseExecutor)